# How to calculate difference between non-consecutive rows in Python DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following pandas DataFrame and trying to create a new "Value_Diff" column where it calculates the difference between current "value" if lable=0 with the previous value where label=1. If label=1 it sets the "Value_Diff" equals to 0. This process needs to be repeated for each group and if first label in the group is equal to 0 it should leave the "Value_Diff" equal to 0 until it reaches first label=1 and then follow the same logic ( group C in this example)

I can write a for loop and if statement for each individual group to do this, however was wondering if there is a better way to do this with using groupby, lambda or any other function.

here is the input:

```
 group  Date         Value   label   
 A     2020-03-01   -117    1           
 A     2020-03-02   -121    0             
 A     2020-03-03   -122    0           
 A     2020-03-04   -122    1           
 B     2020-03-05   -118    1           
 B     2020-03-06   -122    0           
 B     2020-03-07   -124    0           
 B     2020-03-08   -126    0           
 B     2020-03-09   -126    1           
 C     2020-03-10   -130    0           
 C     2020-03-11   -140    0           
 C     2020-03-12   -150    1           
 C     2020-03-13   -160    0
```

Answer should look like this:

```
 group  Date        Value  label   Value_Diff
 A     2020-03-01   -117    1         0
 A     2020-03-02   -121    0         4 (-117-(-121)=4)
 A     2020-03-03   -122    0         1
 A     2020-03-04   -122    1         0
 B     2020-03-05   -118    1         0
 B     2020-03-06   -122    0         4
 B     2020-03-07   -124    0         2
 B     2020-03-08   -126    0         2
 B     2020-03-09   -126    1         0
 C     2020-03-10   -130    0         0
 C     2020-03-11   -140    0         0  
 C     2020-03-12   -150    1         0  
 C     2020-03-13   -160    0         10
```

Sorry my first output didn't actually reflect what I wanted, because @BENY provided the solution to this output I'll leave this here to help others with the same question.
Here is how the actual output should look like.

```
 group  Date        Value  label   Value_Diff
 A     2020-03-01   -117    1         0
 A     2020-03-02   -121    0         4 (-117-(-121)=4)
 A     2020-03-03   -122    0         5 (-117-(-122)=5)
 A     2020-03-04   -122    1         0
 B     2020-03-05   -118    1         0
 B     2020-03-06   -122    0         4 (-122-(-118)=4)
 B     2020-03-07   -124    0         6 (-124-(-118)=6)
 B     2020-03-08   -126    0         8 (-126-(-118)=8)
 B     2020-03-09   -126    1         0
 C     2020-03-10   -130    0         0
 C     2020-03-11   -140    0         0  
 C     2020-03-12   -150    1         0  
 C     2020-03-13   -160    0         10 (-150-(-160)=10)
```

Comment: Why does your 3rd row have a value diff of 1?

Comment: @nms : Thank you so much, you are correct, I forgot to adjust value reference to match my problem statement it should actually be 5, ( -117-122=5), I will edit my post to replicate that.

Comment: This is quite a complicated operation. What is the end-goal?  What will 'Value_Diff' be used for? I ask because maybe there is a better way to achieve what you are ultimately trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I figured it would be complicated. Well this is inventory/supply problem. Ignore the negative numbers for now. Value supposed to be indicative of inventory in a store and label is identifier for when customer refilling its inventory. I am trying to get the inventory difference between ("Value_Diff" columns) between each time that customer refilling its inventory.

Answer (score 2):

We can try with `cummax` create the 1st condition, then use `groupby` with `diff`

```
s = df.groupby('group').label.cummax()
df['new'] = -df.groupby('group').Value.diff().fillna(0).where(s==1 & df.label.ne(1),0)
df
Out[135]: 
   group        Date  Value  label   new
0      A  2020-03-01   -117      1  -0.0
1      A  2020-03-02   -121      0   4.0
2      A  2020-03-03   -122      0   1.0
3      A  2020-03-04   -122      1  -0.0
4      B  2020-03-05   -118      1  -0.0
5      B  2020-03-06   -122      0   4.0
6      B  2020-03-07   -124      0   2.0
7      B  2020-03-08   -126      0   2.0
8      B  2020-03-09   -126      1  -0.0
9      C  2020-03-10   -130      0  -0.0
10     C  2020-03-11   -140      0  -0.0
11     C  2020-03-12   -150      1  -0.0
12     C  2020-03-13   -160      0  10.0
```

Comment: Thanks Beny, I haven't used cummax, and ".ne" before, so I definitely learned those tricks. I only used ".where" in pyspark and now I know I can use it in Pandas. As @nms mentioned I made a quick mistake on showing my output that I am going to update on my post, however I will leave the original questions as I think your solution will be definitely helpful for this post.

Answer (score 1):

I find it's best to do these things one step at a time.  I think this does (the second version) of what you want:

```
df['Value_Last'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.label == 1, 'Value_Last'] = df.loc[df.label == 1, 'Value']
df_grouped = df.groupby('group')
df['Value_Last'] = df_grouped['Value_Last'].ffill()
df['Value_Diff'] = (df['Value_Last'] - df['Value']).fillna(0)


   group        Date  Value  label  Value_Last  Value_Diff
0      A  2020-03-01   -117      1      -117.0         0.0
1      A  2020-03-02   -121      0      -117.0         4.0
2      A  2020-03-03   -122      0      -117.0         5.0
3      A  2020-03-04   -122      1      -122.0         0.0
4      B  2020-03-05   -118      1      -118.0         0.0
5      B  2020-03-06   -122      0      -118.0         4.0
6      B  2020-03-07   -124      0      -118.0         6.0
7      B  2020-03-08   -126      0      -118.0         8.0
8      B  2020-03-09   -126      1      -126.0         0.0
9      C  2020-03-10   -130      0         NaN         0.0
10     C  2020-03-11   -140      0         NaN         0.0
11     C  2020-03-12   -150      1      -150.0         0.0
12     C  2020-03-13   -160      0      -150.0        10.0
```

PS: If the `'Value'` column contains only integers then you can use `.astype(int)` on the end of the last line to convert `'Value_Diff'` back to integers.